# prevent vi from partially highlighting variable names that contain python keywords

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vi, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm having trouble with vi's lexical highlighting on variables that contain builtins or keywords.  For instance, a python variable like `missions_in_window` will have partial highlighting on the word "in" while the rest of the variable stays a default color.  See the example image below.

Is it possible to prevent this highlighting?  This is just a pet peeve, but it's distracting to the point that I'll change a variable's name to avoid the issue.  My `.vimrc` is [here](https://github.com/yosemitebandit/dotdotdot/blob/master/vim/_vimrc) if that is helpful.

[image: vi partial keyword highlighting]

Comment: I do not see this behavior. Are you using the latest version of Vim, currently 7.4?

Comment: What plugins are you using? Can you reproduce the issue with vim -u NONE -N -c 'filetype plugin on' foobar.py?

Comment: @PeterRincker I am  also on 7.4.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I have syntastic, YCM and others.  All of my plugins are [here](https://github.com/yosemitebandit/dotdotdot/tree/master/vim/bundle).  I do not see the formatting (or any formatting, for that matter) with your suggested command.

Comment: If you `set isk-=_` and refresh the screen the _in_ and _with_ lines highlight. Setting `set isk+=_` and refreshing the screen removes the highlighting. See if something is playing with the setting of isk

Comment: @Steve - thanks, that seems to have been it!  I have `isk+=_` in my `vimrc` to make it easier to navigate around underscores.  But I'll take it out if that means I can get rid of this annoying highlighting, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've `:set iskeyword-=_`, Vim will treat `missions_in_window` as three separate keywords: `missions`, `in`, `window`, and the `in` is highlighted by the Python syntax script.

The solution is simple: Don't do that. To navigate through and edit fragments of those variables, you can use my [camelcasemotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905).